# How to parse JSON encoded array in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I had a list 'result' in controller and I converted this list to json using below code.

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string output = jss.Serialize(result);
```

.Now I need to parse the Json result in jQuery.for that I put `var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))` in javascript and I got model as :

```
ContentEncoding: null
ContentType: null
Data: "[{"type":"Size","ID":16,"title":"10X20","value":null,"isDefault":true,"Rate":0,"Product_ID":42,"Parent_ID":0},{"type":"Size","ID":17,"title":"10X18","value":null,"isDefault":false,"Rate":0,"Product_ID":42,"Parent_ID":0},{"type":"Size","ID":18,"title":"10X15","value":null,"isDefault":false,"Rate":0,"Product_ID":42,"Parent_ID":0}]"
JsonRequestBehavior: 1
MaxJsonLength: null
RecursionLimit: null
```

Comment: Use `JSON.parse(model.Data)`.

Comment: Pleas use the search before you ask a new question.